# Using jQuery in a Blackboard Building Block

Tags: java, jquery

Shot in the dark here, but I'm trying to use jQuery in a custom building block of type module for Blackboard: http://www.blackboard.com/, and would love to know the tag structure I'm suppose to use to get this accomplished.

I have tried several combinations of the tags in the library to get this done.  Here is my latest attempt:

```
<%@page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="blackboard.data.user.*" %>
<%@page import="blackboard.platform.session.*" %>
<%@page import="blackboard.persist.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@taglib uri="/bbData" prefix="bbData" %>
<%@taglib uri="/bbUI" prefix="bbUI" %>
<%@taglib uri="/bbNG" prefix="bbNG" %>

<bbUI:docTemplateHead>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
</script>
</bbUI:docTemplateHead>


html here...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried asking on the developer forums on www.edugarage.com or Bb developer listserv http://lists.vcu.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A0=BB-OPEN_SRC ?

BTW, from what I recall, BlackBoard uses Prototype, not jQuery, so these may conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct in that Blackboard Learn uses prototype.js. Because both prototype and jQuery use $, you must use jQuery.noConflict(). This should solve your issue.